# $y'(1)$ and $z'(1)$ of $x^2+y^2-2z^2 = 0, x^2+2y^2+z^2 = 4$

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

Given this equation system

$$x^2+y^2-2z^2 = 0$$

$$x^2+2y^2+z^2 = 4$$

locally at $(1,1,1)$

It can be solved by:

$$ x^2+y^2-2z^2 = 0  \tag 1$$

$$x^2+2y^2+z^2 = 4 \tag 2$$

$2 \times (1) - (2)$ gives
$$x^2-5z^2 = -4 $$

$2 \times (2) + (1)$ gives
$$3x^2+5y^2 = 8 $$

In the neighbourhood of $(1,1,1)$ the intersection can be parametrized as

$$I(x) = \bigg (x, \sqrt{  \frac {8-3x^2}5} , \sqrt{  \frac {4+x^2}5  } \bigg )    $$

But how can one find out $y'(1)$ and $z'(1)$?

Comment: Can you not just take the derivative of the second and third coordinate of $I$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $x^2-5z(x)^2 = -4$ we derive $2x-10z(x)z'(x)=0.$ With $x=1$ and $z(1)=1$ we get

$$2-10z'(1)=0.$$

Hence $z'(1)=1/5.$

It is now your turn to compute $y'(1)$ with the aid of $3x^2+5y^2 = 8.$